# AJAX addEventListener - passing parameters to another function

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

I'll keep this short - I've got a list of `buttons`, that I create using a loop, and when one of them gets clicked I want to be able to pass its id attribute to another file in order to dynamically generate a new page.

Here's the code:

```
for (var i in data.contacts) {  
    var temp = document.createElement('div'); 
    temp.className = "contacts"; 
    var dude = document.createElement('input');
    dude.type = "button"; 
    dude.value = data.contacts[i];
    dude.id = data.contacts[i]; 
    dude.className = "dude_button" + data.contacts[i]; 

    dude.addEventListener('click', function(event) { gotoProfile(dude.id); }, false); 


    temp.appendChild(dude); 
    temp.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    theDiv.appendChild(temp); 

}
// and now in another file, there's gotoProfile():

function gotoProfile(x) {
var username = document.getElementById(x).value;  

if (xmlHttp) {
    try { 
.... etc.
```

Now see this works, sort of, but the problem is that when I click any button, it only passes the last `dude.id` value from the list `data.contacts`. Obviously I want every button's `addEventListener` to pass its own `data.contacts[i]` value, instead of just the last one.

Help appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JavaScript has no block scope, `dude` will refer to the last assigned element (because the loop finished) when the event handler is called. You have to `capture` the reference to the current `dude` by e.g. using an immediate function:

```
dude.addEventListener('click', (function(d) {
    return function(event) { 
        gotoProfile(d.id); 
    }
}(dude)), false);
```

This is a common error when creating functions in a loop.

---

But you can make it even easier. The `event` object has a property `target` that points to the element the event was raised on. So you can just do:

```
dude.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    gotoProfile(event.target.id); 
}, false);
```

And with that said, you don't need to add a handler for every button. As you are doing the same for every button,  you could attach the same event handler above to the parent of the buttons (or a common ancestor) and it would still work. You just have to filter out the clicks that don't happen on a button:

```
parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && event.target.type == "button") {
        gotoProfile(event.target.id); 
    }
}, false);
```